# UIBlurEffectView doesn't fill the whole element

Tags: swift, mkmapview, bounds, uiblureffect

I have a MKMapView which fills the whole screen.

I want to blur the map with this code in Swift:

```
var blurMap = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
var blurMapView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurMap)
blurMapView.frame = mapView.bounds
mapView.addSubview(blurMapView)
```

It works, but with bigger screens (iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus) the blur affects just to a part of the map. With iPhone 4s and 5/5s the blur fills all the screen.

[image]

This is with iPhone 6/6 plus. If I run it with an iPhone 4/5/5s it works great.

I don't know if it could the problem of the simulator, I don't have any iPhone 6 so I can't test it in a real device.

What would you think this issue comes from?

Comment: It is preferred if you could show the image in the post, instead of asking others to go to (possibly malicious) sites.

Comment: Thanks for editing, I could't post the image because I wasn't allowed :P

Comment: Where do you add the blur effect? In which function?

Comment: I declarate the blur effect with the lines below:
var blurMap = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
var blurMapView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurMap)

Then I add the subview: mapView.addSubview(blurMapView)

Comment: @AitorSola, I think Arbitur is asking what function is this code in?  Is it in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, other?  It's possible that the blur view is being added before auto-layout has finished resizing the map view (ie. map view size changes after the blur view is added).  Also, I wouldn't add it as a subview of the map view but as a subview of the map view's parent (to self.view and setting frame to mapView.frame).

Comment: Oh excuse me! The code is in ViewDidLoad. How would you modify the code or where would you place the code?

Comment: @Anna this happen only in iPhone 6 and 6 plus. Not in iPhone 4, 5, 5s. It happens when the screen is big.